# How to transmit auth data to WordPress REST API using cURL?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I cannot figure out how to transmit the required auth data during a post request with curl.

```
$data = array(
        
    "title" => "tite",
    "content" => "content",
    "status" => "draft",
    "author" => 1
        
);
    
$ch = curl_init();
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USER:PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
    
curl_close( $ch );
```

This results in the error message:

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

I have no idea what I did wrong. The username and password are definitely correct.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: To be clear, are you attempting to send WordPress credentials or HTTP Basic Auth credentials? `CURLOPT_USERPWD` is only for the latter.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that is a good point. i think i have to send WordPress credentials. during my research i only found that way. do you know how i can send wordpress credentials?

Comment: This flow doesn't work with native WordPress passwords. Instead you are encouraged to create [Application Passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) for a given user.